# .JSP file Mapping not working (throws error 404)

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm building a site using Java WEB EE, and although I'm a total newbie, I'm getting the hang of it. Anyway, I've looked everywhere, but I have not found a way to hide the .jsp extensions when loading a jsp file. I found that you could hide it by making a servlet mapping, and in my case this is what I wrote in the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
     <jsp-file>test.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*(Note: I have also tried putting /test.jsp instead of test.jsp, but it didn't work anyway.)*

However, when I try to load test.jsp from index, using /test as the href tag:

```
<a href="/test"></i>Test</a>
```

I get the 404 error, which means it didn't find the webpage.

When I do it without servlet mapping, it works perfectly, but I really wanna hide that ugly extension.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "/" before your jsp

```
   <servlet>
         <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
         <jsp-file>/test.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow, I changed the href tag to

```
<a href="test"></i>Test</a>
```

(deleted the "/") and finally worked